# apparently same commits give different sha1, why?

Tags: git, commit, sha1

After re-write of a subtree history from a repository with a script of mine, I compared it with what would do a `git filter-branch ...` on that same subtree. I see that initial commits have different sha1 although I expected them to be identical (consequence of this is that all commits from both histories have different sha1).

Doing a `git show --format=raw <commit-sha1>` on both commits gives exactly the same output (except for first line, which is `commit <commit-sha1>`, introducing the result).

Object files are completely different, but as they are binaries, I can't figure out the root cause.

Assuming all git versions are consistent with each other, what could explain to have 2 different sha1?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe a changing email, a changing commit date, or similar meta-information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Git's inputs to a commit hash include metadata such as the SHA1 of the tree, the SHA1 of the parent, the commiter's name, email and commit date, and the author's name, email and commit date. So when you rewrote history, the commiter commit date and the tree (since you did a `filter-branch`) have probably changed, hence the difference in your commit's SHA1.

For more information about the format of a commit, you can use `git cat-file commit <sha>`, or look up the [Git Objects section of the Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

Comment: All tree, parents, emails, dates, names from author and committer were reported. Meanwhile, your suggestion to use `git cat-file` helped as I am seeing an extra '\n' in the logged comments, while I do not see any difference with `git show`. I am checking this.

Comment: I've seen that some tool sometime add an extra empty line at the end of the commit message when there is none (so that it ends with an empty line). Maybe this is what happens in your case?

Comment: I confirm my script wrongly added a newline. I fixed that and have the same sha1 now. Thank you Sylvain.