# Git showing non-existent carriage-returns

Tags: git, patch, carriage-return

I am working on a FOSS project and I have my nice local git repo.
Recently it happens *sometimes* that I submit a patch and it cannot be applied:

```
error: foo.xml: patch does not apply
Did you hand edit your patch?
It does not apply to blobs recorded in its index.
Cannot fall back to three-way merge.
```

and when this happens it's always due to files which add carriage-returns.

I look into the `git-diff` and I see those (damned) carriage-returns `^M` that I see at the end of the lines.

They shouldn't be there, I don't use Windows either, and `vim` only sees normal newlines `\n`. It feels like a kind of poltergeist, and I am getting scared.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

> $git am -3 --ignore-whitespace /c/temp/git/format_since_origin.patch

Check this complete thread for more help: [Error while applying a patch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190679/error-while-applying-a-patch-in-git)