# Create patch or diff file from git repository and apply it to another different git repository

Tags: git, diff, patch, git-diff, git-apply

I work on WordPress based project and I want to patch my project at each new release version of WP. For this, I want generate a patch between two commits or tags.

For example, in my repo `/www/WP` I do this:

```bash
$ git patch-format com1..com2 --stdout > '~/patchs/mypatch.patch'

# or

$ git patch-format tag1..tag2 --stdout > '~/patchs/mypatch.patch'
```

`/www/WP` git natif WordPress

`/www/myproject` My git project WordPress based

The `git apply` command line doesn't work, I think because we are in different repositories.

Can I generate a patch file without a commit, just a differential and apply it to another git repository?

Answer (score 421):

You can just use `git diff` to produce a [unified diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format) suitable for `git apply`:

```
git diff tag1..tag2 > mypatch.patch
```

You can then apply the resulting patch with:

```
git apply mypatch.patch
```

Comment: Thank you Enrico, I used `$git diff -u tag1..tag2 > mypatch.patch` and `$git apply --stat > mypatch.patch` the answer is `0 files changed` any other suggestion please ? :)

Comment: You need to specify the path to the patch file as an argument of `git apply`. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I used `git diff -p tag1 tag2 > my.patch` which worked well.

Comment: How do I make patches in unified diff format? https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Contribution%20checklist#Proper_Formatted_Unified_diff_of_the_Changes says `Only unified diff (-uNr) format is acceptable.` but when I try `git diff -uNr tag1..tag2 > mypatch.patch` I get the message `usage: git diff [<options>] [<commit> [<commit>]] [--] [<path>...]`

Comment: if you use VSCode and preffer GUI then this plugin will also work
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paragdiwan.gitpatch

Comment: In my case I had a new repo and wanted to create a patch with all the changes from beginning , tagged the first commit 0.0.1 and last one as 0.0.2 and then created a patch with ```git diff 0.0.1 0.0.2 > changes.patch```

Comment: Be careful `git diff ...` + `git apply ...` do not handle deleted / moved files properly ... when `git format-patch ...` + `git am ...` do.

Comment: I think this doesn‘t work with binary files.

Comment: Also can be useful: `git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace mypatch.patch`

Answer (score 75):

To produce patch for several commits, you should use `format-patch` git command, e.g.

```
git format-patch -k --stdout R1..R2
```

This will export your commits into patch file in mailbox format.

To generate patch for the last commit, run:

```
git format-patch -k --stdout HEAD~1
```

Then in another repository apply the patch by `am` git command, e.g.

```
git am -3 -k file.patch
```

See: [`man git-format-patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-format-patch) and [`git-am`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-am).

Comment: What about a patch that can be applied with `patch -p1`? https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Contribution%20checklist#Proper_Formatted_Unified_diff_of_the_Changes

Comment: I was moving patch from linux to winodws, so had to use --ignore-whitespace as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190679/error-while-applying-a-patch-in-git

Comment: @AaronFranke, you can try '-p' option: git format-patch -p HEAD^1

Comment: Of note, this has the advantage of keeping the commit messages, author, & commit dates of the original commits.

Comment: `--stdout` would dump the output into the terminal, which you'd need to pipe using `> file.patch`. Alternatively, if you don't include `--stdout` it generates files in the format `nnnn-commt-message.patch` (where `nnnn` is a rolling number starting from `0001`).

Comment: Also, kindly explain the options `-3` and `-k` in your answer. Personally I don't think `-k` is necessary here but I'm not too sure about `-3`.

Comment: I share @ADTC's reaction. Fwiw, **format-patch**: _`-k, --keep-subject`
Do not strip/add [PATCH] from the first line of the commit log message_ and **am**: _`-k, --keep`
Pass -k flag to git mailinfo (see [git-mailinfo(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-mailinfo))_ [seems same as previous -k] and  _`-3, --3way`
When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge_. Imo, a 3-way merge for conflicts is always a good idea, as you can handle conflicts like you would in your normal workflow instead of the command failing, eg. `-k` seems take it or leave it, subjective preference.

Answer (score 56):

You can apply two commands

1. `git diff --patch > mypatch.patch` // to generate the patch`
2. `git apply mypatch.patch` // to apply the patch`

Answer (score 3):

As a complementary, to produce patch for only one specific commit, use:

```
git format-patch -1 <sha>
```

When the patch file is generated, make sure your other repo knows where it is when you use `git am ${patch-name}`

Before adding the patch, use `git apply --check ${patch-name}` to make sure that there is no confict.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of this command.

```
git diff master..localbranch > file.patch
```

Answer (score 2):

You even can do patches only for sub directory you are currently in. Just add `.`

```
git format-patch -k b365cce8..80a2c18a .
```

Then you can apply them:

```
git am *.patch
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418860/4632019) for details