# Create patch or diff file from git repository for target directory and apply it to another different git repository with different directory

Tags: git, git-patch, git-am

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28192623/4632019) is similar question.

```
git format-patch -k R1..R2
```

But I want only commits from current directory and removing relative path or change path at all

For example by doing:

```
git format-patch -k R1..R2 .
```

I get patches with `ext/DbAccess/Mojolicious/Command/db_env.pm` path. But I want `Mojolicious/Command/db_env.pm` because I am currently at `ext/DbAccess` directory.

Is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't `git apply` apply the patch regardless your current in-git directory?

Comment: @fluffy: is says that file `ext/DbAccess/Mojolicious/Command/db_env.pm` does not exists at current repository

Comment: It was not really clear from your question assuming you only changed your current directory. I'm afraid you have to fix file paths before applying the patch.