# Can we use/pick-up commit of one program into another similar program?

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, commit

I have two similar programs(with almost same file hierarchy) with some differences and both are separate bitbucket repository. I have added some feature in the first program and wondering of using its commits to reproduce the same feature in the second program?

It maybe a silly idea as programs are separate, but I am thinking that way because the files I have modified have exactly the same hierarchy in both the repositories. Is it feasible to do anything like that? Or I have to manually copy/paste the changes...

**UPDATE:**

As suggested in comment by Enrico Campidoglio, one of the solution approach for this can be by using `diff` and `format-patch` mentioned here: [Create patch or diff file from git repository and apply it to another different git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192623/create-patch-or-diff-file-from-git-repository-and-apply-it-to-another-different)

Comment: take a look at this, might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another

Comment: @iatharva looks like it is not the same scenario, there the problem is related to two repo for the same program unlike here

Comment: Okay, my bad (I missed that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create patch or diff file from git repository and apply it to another different git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192623/create-patch-or-diff-file-from-git-repository-and-apply-it-to-another-different)

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio Yes, that is correct. But if you look closely, my question emphasis on the general solution approach for merging changes in two different programs and the other question is straightforward asking for the working of `diff` and `format-patch`. Although I totally agree with you...

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio I used the `format-patch` and it is working fine. Is there a way to patch say `diff.patch` in a single commit history instead of logging all the commits used during creation of patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export each single commit by:

`git format-patch -{NUMBER_OF_BACKWARD_COMMITS} {STARTING_COMMIT_HASH} --stdout > diff.patch`

Then apply the patch generated file **on the other repository** by:

`git am < diff.path`.

Comment: can you explain those two arguments `NUMBER_OF_BACKWARD_COMMITS` and `STARTING_COMMIT_HASH`? I have a consecutive list of commits to apply to another repo...

Comment: You have to write down the hash of the last commit you want to export (STARTING_COMMIT_HASH) and how many commit before this you want to include (NUMBER_OF_BACKWARD_COMMITS).

Comment: I used the `format-patch` and it is working fine. Is there a way to patch the `diff.patch` in a single commit history instead of logging all the commits used during creation of patch?

Comment: If I remember, you should remove `--stdout > diff.patch` in order to get a singole patch file for each commit of the history you selected.