# How to cherrypick a commit from repo1 to repo2

Tags: git, egit

I have 2 git repos repo1 and repo2. I am working on repo1 and sometimes I have to commit the same stuff on both repos. I would like to avoid coppying files to other project and do commit again same thing.

How can I just cherrypick my commit on repo1 into repo2?

Comment: Use git format-patch / git am on their respective sides, or combine the cherry-pick source repository into the destination one temporarily (using git fetch for example) and do git cherry-pick. Not sure if it's possible to "commit into two repositories" at once.

Comment: I solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68983860/418599 the same issue.