# How can we resolve git patch merge conflicts manually on a system where no graphical diff/merge tool is available

Tags: git

I am facing an issue when applying git patch to a branch. Following command is showing that patch can not be applied but git mergetool is not showing any conflicts

```
git am -3 < changes.patch
```

Found something similar at:
[git am error: "patch does not apply"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846189/git-am-error-patch-does-not-apply)

Comment: What do `git status` and `git diff` show?

Comment: Open with any text editor and look for strings of the form `<<<<`, `=====` and `>>>>>`

Answer (score 1):

You can type git status and all the files with the merge conflicts will be with the status of `both modified`.

Than you can simply edit them with any editor like vi/nano and resolve the conflicts.

---

You can also add the `--reject` flag and the rejected parts will be written to a `.rej` file