# Git CRLF and LF line ending on windows/linux

Tags: git, newline, patch, carriage-return, linefeed

I am working on a project which uses both CRLF and LF line endings. I am working on windows.

- I created a patch that converts a file from using CRLF line endings to LF line endings.
- I then formatted the patch with `git format-patch`. When I open this patch, it has correct LF line endings. The patch says the file is similar at 97% (only the line endings have been changed).
- I sent it to someone using `git send-email`. When I observe the mail sent with wireshark, all the line endings have been converted to CRLF.
- When someone else receive this patch (working on windows aswell), all the line endings are CRLF in the patch.
- The patch can be applied, but the file which should have seen its line endings modified remains the same: no LF line ending conversion. When using `git show HEAD`, the file is said to be similar at 100%, even though the patch being applied said there should be a similarity of 97%.

How is it possible to send a patch with LD line ending on windows ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to add a `.gitattributes` rule for that file, in order to [force lf for that file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42135910/6309)

```
a_file text=auto eol=lf
```

But regarding your send-email issue, see "[`git am/format-patch`: control format of line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28257267/6309)", try and use [`git send-email --transfer-encoding=base64`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email#Documentation/git-send-email.txt---transfer-encoding7bit8bitquoted-printablebase64auto), to make sure everything is preserved (including eol)

Comment: I didn t have to use the .gitattributes. The base64 encoding worked. Thank you for your time.